# For an nxm matrix A, what is dim(im(A)) + dim(ker(A^T))?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I know that the rank nullity theorem says that $dim(im(A)) + dim(ker(A))$ is the number of column in the matrix, and that seems like it would be useful, but here we have $A^T$ instead of A, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dimension of row space is equal to dimension of column space, $$\dim(im(A))=\dim(im(A^T)).$$

Hence $$\dim(im(A))+\dim(ker(A^T))=\dim(im(A^T))+\dim(ker(A^T))=n$$

Comment: How do you know the dimension of the row space is equal to the dimension of the column space?

Comment: Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ be a matrix such that its columns form a basis for column space of $A$, hence, there exists a matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$ such that $A=BC$.

Since $C$ has $k$ rows, we can see that dimension of row space of $A\leq k$, the dimension of column space of $A$.

If we repeat the argument on $A^T$, dimension of column space of $A$ is less than equal to dimension of row space of $A$.

Hence the two quantity are the same.

Answer (score 1):

$dim(im(A^T))=dim(im(A))$ because the dimension of the space spanned by the columns of a matrix (the right hand side of the equality - talking about matrix $A$) is the same as that spanned by its rows (the left hand side of the equality - talking about matrix $A$). Hence, using the equality you mentioned : 
\begin{equation}dim(ker(A^T)) + dim(im(A))= dim(ker(A^T)) + dim(im(A^T)) = n\end{equation} where $n$ is the number of **rows** of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to find the answer ($n$) using the rank-nullity theorem.  However, a more natural way to see it is to note that the two spaces $im(A)$ and $\ker(A^T)$ are *orthogonal complements* in $\Bbb R^n$.  That is,
$$
\ker(A^T) = \{x: x \perp y \quad \forall y \in \operatorname{im}(A)\} = \operatorname{im}(A)^{\perp}
$$
Thus, the dimensions of the spaces should add up to $n$.